# Speak c# delegates

Tags: c#, delegates

I learned delegates now with this videoseries: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nd-tcQcslc&list=PLdbkZkVDyKZVvizO94tJNmTfRzXWGDFZ3&index=2

When he talks about delegates it's very confusing to follow him as a beginner, because he does use the word for two different things.

He does use it for eg `Func<T, ..., Tresult>` // He does call this delegate

`delegate(Person p) { return p.ToString(); }` // He does also call this a delegate (a anonymus delegate)

Whats the correct way to talk about delegates? 
I'm pretty sure the second one is just called anonymus function/method and the delegate-keyword is ony syntax there and I also think that the first one should be referenced by the word delegate when talking about delegates.

Comment: they are both delegates. the latter is referred to as anonymous delegates but rarely used lately due to lambda expressions.

Comment: ok and the object that gets instaniated by assigning a method to a variable of the type of a delegate is called delegate-object? And how do you call a delegate variable? Variable of the type of a delegate?

Answer (score 0):

`Func<T>` and its generic "overloads" are, most accurately, general-purpose named delegate types. They are not "anonymous" per se, but they can be assigned from an anonymous delegate that matches the method signature of the delegate type (number and type of parameters and return type). The `Func`, `Action`, `Comparison`, `Predicate` etc. types are named delegate types, just like any custom delegate type you would declare yourself such as for an event handler.

It's important, at least at first, to differentiate between a "delegate" and a "delegate type". A delegate type is to a delegate what a class is to an instance when talking about "objects" in code. The type is the definition, the actual delegate is a specific instance of a delegate type.

The syntax `delegate(int a){...}` is the original syntax for an "anonymous delegate", aka a "function literal", before the cleaner-looking "lambda statement" (`a => ...`) became a thing. Lambda statements are a form of anonymous delegate and the two formats are 1:1 interchangeable. Either of these, as well as any named method, can also be assigned as an instance of a "named delegate", which was C#'s original way of specifying a "function variable", which is the basic concept that delegates fulfill in C#.

Comment: "It's important, at least at first, to differentiate between a "delegate" and a "delegate type". A delegate type is to a delegate what a class is to an instance when talking about "objects" in code. The type is the definition, the actual delegate is a specific instance of a delegate type." Are you sure that not both are called delegates? Like int a = 5; // 5 and int is called Integer. Liek you say I would have to call a variable of the a delegate-type a delegate-type-varaible. Sounds strange. And every method would be also called delegate. Sounds also strange.

Comment: msdn does call the delegate type a delegate and the method as method and not delegate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx

Comment: There is no such thing as an _"anonymous delegate"_; all delegates have names. There is just "delegate", which can be created from an "anonymous method". There is also no such thing, in the parlance of C#, as a _"function literal"_; the term is used in the context of other languages, but will just confuse C# programmers. There is no such thing as a _"lambda statement"_, anywhere. In C#, there is a _"lambda expression"_, and colloquially (i.e. not mentioned in the spec) a _"statement lambda"_, and neither of these are mutually exclusive with the term _"function literal"_.

Comment: Ordinarily, these inaccuracies might be forgiven, but since the OP's question is _entirely_ about terminology and correct usage of it, having an answer that is so misleading and inaccurate is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

> Whats the correct way to talk about delegates?

Arguably, possibly a matter of opinion. However, the C# specification is clear:

- a "delegate" is an instance of a "delegate type". That is, an instance of a *type* declared using `delegate`, inheriting the base class `System.Delegate`.
- There is no such thing as a "delegate method". That phrase does not appear in the C# language specification even once. Rather, the thing your instructor (i.e. the person in the video) is calling a "delegate method", is actually an **anonymous method** (which is itself one kind of **anonymous function**…the other way to declare an anonymous function is with a lambda expression).

From the C# 5 language specification:

> A delegate type represents references to methods with a particular parameter list and return type. Delegates make it possible to treat methods as entities that can be assigned to variables and passed as parameters. Delegates are similar to the concept of function pointers found in some other languages, but unlike function pointers, delegates are object-oriented and type-safe.

Do note that in the context of other languages (e.g. Objective-C), the term "delegate" has a more conventional meaning, somewhat different from the precise usage in the context of C#. And of course, even in the context of C#, you will find people using the term imprecisely, to describe e.g. the target method of a delegate instance, rather than the delegate instance itself.

Comment: seems like microsoft is not consistent in their documentation with the wording

Comment: @Gernot: could be, though you'd have to be more specific. I'm not aware of documentation that conflicts. Regardless though, the specification is the only thing that is definitive.